# Rails 3 DB connection pool - connections not closing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Stack is Rails 3 / Postgres + mongrel. I recently had to increase the connection pool because hits on one of the mongrels were always timing out. I reasoned that with 3 mongrels + a delayed_job running on each, I'd need 6 connections in the pool (it was set to 5). I increased this to 10 in database.yml and it resolved the timeout issues, now though when I monitor connections in PG I am seeing this sort of thing;

```
SELECT datname,usename,procpid,client_addr,waiting,query_start,current_query FROM pg_stat_activity;


db1   | www-data |    8658 |             | f       | 2014-03-19 10:03:54.084825+00 | <IDLE>
db1   | www-data |    9071 |             | f       | 2014-03-19 09:58:42.306558+00 | <IDLE>
db1   | www-data |    8721 |             | f       | 2014-03-19 10:03:53.980691+00 | <IDLE>
db1   | www-data |    8722 |             | f       | 2014-03-19 10:03:53.874443+00 | <IDLE>
db1   | www-data |    8733 |             | f       | 2014-03-19 10:04:20.380137+00 | <IDLE>
db1   | www-data |    9080 |             | f       | 2014-03-19 10:00:54.157541+00 | <IDLE>
db1   | www-data |   10843 |             | f       | 2014-03-19 10:04:18.506355+00 | <IDLE>
#and so on and so on for more than 20 instances...
```

It baloons up to more than 20 connections and seemingly isn't closing them (I'm assuming that the presence of  still means they're open, just not doing anything). It does seem to go up and down, so *some* connections are being closed.

I thought rails/activerecord was supposed to close its connections automatically but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Have I read this correctly? Do I have a leak somewhere? What could be causing it?

Comment: Are you using something like sidekiq/delayed job or otherwise using activerecord in a different thread?

Comment: We do have a delayed_job going, but with three mongrels I would expect 3x connections (one for each instance) plus 3x connections (one for each delayed_job) giving a total of 6 active connections, not 20+

Answer (score 2):

When using ActiveRecord transactions outside of actions initiated by a controller e.g. in a delayed job, you must use the following syntax to ensure connections are returned to the pool

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
  #your code here
end
```

Comment: That's rather disturbing if that's the case, and would actually explain why it's happening. Is there a source somewhere you know of that confirms this to be the case (I can't find any mention in the documentation) - We're using rails 3.2.2

Comment: I read about it [here](https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch). The reason you don't need to do this normally is that taking connections from the pool and returning them is automatically performed by ActionController